# Crossfade images in Safari not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I'm working on a project where I need to make a dynamically loaded full-screen image background that crossfades new images every so many seconds. 
The script works now fine in most browsers, but on Safari the transition effects don't apply. In stead of nicely transitioning to the next image, the image disappears for 1.5s (the time it should do over the transition).
Does anyone know how I can fix this? I've tried to solve it using webkits on the transition of the opacity, but it didn't work out.

Here some of the code

**Script.js**

```
const images = {
  init(imageArray) {
    elements.image_holders.forEach(function(image, index) {
      image.src = `${config.imageUrl}${imageArray[index]}`;
      config.atImage ++;
    });
    elements.image_groups[0].style.opacity = 1;
    config.imageArray = imageArray;
    this.startInterval();
  },
  startInterval() {
    imageInterval = setInterval(images.changeImage, config.interval);
  },
}
```

In the interval I change opacity every time again and load the new picture dynamically from the image Array.

**_image_groups.scss**

```
.__image_wrapper {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1.5s linear;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.5s linear;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

That is the styling I use for the image to do it's transition effect. I work from `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1`.

Has anyone a idea why the transition doesn't work on Safari? I've looked around on the internet but couldn't find the answer. Thanks!